# Macro thats open File X => File X close the previous file then File X opens another file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file Y that need to open a file X.
Not a problem, but the things get creepy because I need that file X closes the file Y then opens file Z then Z file will closes the X file.
I have to build this bridge because files Y and Z are to large to open both at the same time.
So, when I open the file X he runs the macro ont hat file, but the macro stops before opening the next file.
I have done this:

File Y

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\241410\Desktop\Teste2.xlsb"
```

File X

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call Macro2
End Sub

Sub Macro2()
    Windows("Teste1.xlsb").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\241410\Desktop\Teste1.xlsb"
End Sub
```

File Z will closes the file X and run macros of itself.
The code stops just after the ActiveWorkbook.Close.
To make it clear, File Y = Teste1.xlsb and File X is Teste2.xlsb

Comment: because you close the active workbook, before it was able to open the new one.

Comment: Use `Application.Ontime` to run the macro in X to close Y; then repeat with Z.

Comment: Why not open Z directly or using vbscript?

Comment: Siddharth Rout, I can't make one file open the other directly because of the size of each one. Rory, Can you help me assembling this? I didn't manage to archive this setup.

Answer (score 1):

change the code in File X as followed:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call Macro2
End Sub

Sub Macro2()
    Windows("Teste1.xlsb").Activate
    Workbooks(Name of file Y).close false
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\241410\Desktop\Teste1.xlsb"
End Sub
```

Comment: File Y is Teste1.xlsb... I have tried this, even removing the activate command for the Teste1 file, without success.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use another workbook that contains no data , just code to open and close what you need.